# How to efficiently write a large text file in C#?

Tags: c#, text-files, io

I am creating a method in C# which generates a text file for a [Google Product Feed](http://www.google.com/support/merchants/bin/answer.py?answer=160083&hl=en#optional). The feed will contain upwards of 30,000 records and the text file currently weighs in at ~7Mb.

Here's the code I am currently using (some lines removed for brevity's sake).

```
public static void GenerateTextFile(string filePath) {

  var sb = new StringBuilder(1000);
  sb.Append("availability").Append("\t");
  sb.Append("condition").Append("\t");
  sb.Append("description").Append("\t");
  // repetitive code hidden for brevity ...
  sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);

  var items = inventoryRepo.GetItemsForSale();

  foreach (var p in items) {
    sb.Append("in stock").Append("\t");
    sb.Append("used").Append("\t");
    sb.Append(p.Description).Append("\t");
    // repetitive code hidden for brevity ...
    sb.AppendLine();
  }

  using (StreamWriter outfile = new StreamWriter(filePath)) {
      result.Append("Writing text file to disk.").AppendLine();
      outfile.Write(sb.ToString());
  }
}
```

I am wondering if StringBuilder is the right tool for the job. Would there be performance gains if I used a TextWriter instead?

I don't know a ton about IO performance so any help or general improvements would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Since the time I wrote this question, the Linq2Csv project came to life. It is a much better way to handle the code I was writing. http://nuget.org/packages/LinqToCsv

Comment: any full source code with solution?

Comment: Sorry, it was written for one of my clients. You should really look into Linq2Csv. It will make this sort of thing a lot easier.

Comment: Almost 5 years since my last comment on this question I would highly recommend CsvHelper. https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/

Answer (score 81, accepted):

**File I/O operations are generally well optimized in modern operating systems.** You shouldn't try to assemble the entire string for the file in memory ... just write it out piece by piece. The `FileStream` will take care of buffering and other performance considerations.

You can make this change easily by moving:

```
using (StreamWriter outfile = new StreamWriter(filePath)) {
```

to the top of the function, and getting rid of the `StringBuilder` writing directly to the file instead.

**There are several reasons why you should avoid building up large strings in memory:**

1. It can actually perform worse, because the `StringBuilder` has to increase its capacity as you write to it, resulting in reallocation and copying of memory.
2. It may require more memory than you can physically allocate - which may result in the use of virtual memory (the swap file) which is much slower than RAM.
3. For truly large files (> 2Gb) you will run out of address space (on 32-bit platforms) and will fail to ever complete.
4. To write the `StringBuilder` contents to a file you have to use `ToString()` which effectively doubles the memory consumption of the process since both copies must be in memory for a period of time. This operation may also fail if your address space is sufficiently fragmented, such that a single contiguous block of memory cannot be allocated.

Comment: Nice answer. Tuning may be tried using the StreamWriter constructor overload that lets you define the bufferSize...

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer! I appreciate you taking the time to add some further explanation about how to handle this sort of scenario.

Comment: 5 years later...  is the `FileStream` class still the best method of writing text files ~7MB ?

Answer (score 27):

Just move the `using` statement so it encompasses the whole of your code, and write directly to the file. I see no point in keeping it all in memory first.

Answer (score 13):

Write one string at a time using StreamWriter.Write rather than caching everything in a StringBuilder.

Comment: I really hope you don't mean for him to write one *bit* at a time.

Comment: While this was a good answer. I have a file that is approximately 20Mb in size and the issue I am facing is StreamWriter actually put's a carriage return/new line at the end. I am trying to remove that extra carriage return at the very end and as it was already pointed out StringBuilder is not a great solution for performance or size.
I tried

    StreamReader.Peek()

to peek the line before it reaches the end.
Any ideas?

Comment: @MaximusPeters You probably found your way in the meantime, but perhaps you were using the `WriteLine()` method instead of `Write()`?

Answer (score 4):

This might be old but I had a file to write with about 17 million lines
so I ended up batching the writes every 10k lines similar to these lines

```
for (i6 = 1; i6 <= ball; i6++) 
{ //this is middle of 6 deep nest ..
  counter++;
  // modus to get a value at every so often 10k lines
  divtrue = counter % 10000; // remainder operator % for 10k
  //  build the string of fields with \n at the end 
  lineout = lineout + whatever 
  // the magic 10k block here
  if (divtrue.Equals(0))  
  {
     using (StreamWriter outFile = new StreamWriter(@filepath, true))
     { 
         //  write the 10k lines with .write NOT writeline..
         outFile.Write(lineout); 
     } 
     // reset the string so we dont do silly like memory overflow
     lineout = ""; 
  }
}
```

In my case it was MUCH faster then one line at a time.