# Returning a list of objects from a function to a text file C#

Tags: c#, list, text-files

I have a big function that returns a list of objects. I basically need the results to be put in to a text file. The list contains objects of a class with attributes string Index and integer count. I would want it to be written in a textfile like:
Index : Count fe.

BOOK_FROM_STORE : 27

Anybody has some guidance?

Comment: This might be related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3407216/how-to-efficiently-write-a-large-text-file-in-c

Comment: Why are you returning a list of objects. You should try to be more precisely about what the data you return is presenting. Perhaps a list of strings..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parse the data held by your object to string and then write it to a text file.